# Bind data to Combobox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am trying to bind profile from the list of collectorDTO to Combobox in wpf from list of data, Please find the code below

```
List<CollectorDTO> cdlist = new List<CollectorDTO>();
            cbProfile.ItemsSource = cdlist;
            cbProfile.DisplayMemberPath = "Profile";
            cbProfile.SelectedValuePath = "Profile";
```

Collector DTO contains the following variables with get set method

```
private  int _coldataId;
private string _profile;
private string _protocol;
private string _hosttype;
private string _host;
private string _uid;
private string _pwd;
private string _remdir;
private string _locdir;
private string _database;
private string _audittrail;
private string _skeleton;
private string _tmode;
private string _cmdstr;
private string _starttime;
private string _stoptime;
private int _period;
private string _addinfo;
```

Please Help to bind the data?

Comment: does your list have items? remember you should populate list before binding to Control as Binding to empty collection simply doesnt work

Comment: instead of List<CollectorDTO> use ObservableCollection<CollectorDTO>, CollectorDTO should impliment INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 0):

Your display member path should then be `_profile` instead of `Profile`. Also, ensure that you have populated your list before you set the binding because you are using a normal list which is not an observable collection (the combo box would have no way of knowing you added something to the list after  the binding has been setup).

Comment: OP specified that `the following variables with get set method` so it just private part of the full property. Although there is still a chance it can be named other that `Profile`

Comment: I see, I missed that detail. I guess the only thing to watch out for then is that the items are added to the collection before the binding is setup.

Comment: I have already added the item to the setup but only the binding is not working properly

Answer (score 0):

change your list definition to be public property. Most bindings accept only them:

```
private List<CollectorDTO> _cdlist;
public List<CollectorDTO> cdlist 
{
    get { return _cdlist; }
    set { _cdlist = value; }
}
```

Comment: He is setting the binding in code-behind. Whether the data source is public or private should be irrelevant here.

Comment: So far he doesnt have any property, just variable - this could be a problem